Unable to detect labels correctly in one of our python service
We are using kubernetes cluster for our multiple services out of which there is one service called as aws-detection service. It detects the images and store the image then it detect the correct label of the image. Now when the code runs of this service we are getting error in api service that "something is wrong in AWS rekognitions API".
below is the code of aws-detection service
async def aws_rekognition(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, url, bucketName, filePath, objectName, confidenceValue):
    # open yaml file
    # try:
    with open(secret_path) as f:

        print("Url+++++", url,secret_path)
        logger.remove()
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')

        # create file name
        log_filename = str(now) + '.log'

        # add file name given format
        logger.add(sys.stdout, colorize=True,
                    format='%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(module)s :: %(funcName)s :: %(lineno)d :: %(message)s')

        # add file root path
        logger.add('logs/{}'.format(log_filename))
        logger.info("Connecting")

        # get yaml file value
        config_dict = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        object_url = url
        logger.info(f"request parameter - {object_url}")
        # set aws value
        aws_access_key_id = config_dict['AWS']['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
        aws_secret_access_key = config_dict['AWS']['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        aws_region = config_dict['REGION']['REGION_ID']
        aws_server = config_dict['SERVER']['URL']
        try:
            # connect with boto aws connection
            client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name=aws_region, aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
            # response = requests.get(object_url)
            # connect with s3
            s3_client = create_aws_connection()
            print("s3_client++++++++++++", s3_client)
        except:
            aws_res = {"Status": status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, "Msg": "something is wrong in AWS connection"}
            return JSONResponse(aws_res)
        #BR action call

        # call the image response to s3 client
        file_name = object_url.split('/')[-1]
        try:
            response = client.detect_labels(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket': out_res['bucket_name'],'Name': out_res['path']}}, MaxLabels=10)
        except:
            aws_reko = {"Status": status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, "Msg": "something is wrong in AWS rekognitions API"}
            return JSONResponse(aws_reko)

        try:
            aws_log_bucket = config_dict['BUCKET']['LOG_BUCKET']
            final_log_path = os.path.join("logs", log_filename)
            s3_client.upload_file(final_log_path, aws_log_bucket, log_filename)
        except:
            aws_log = {"Status": status.HTTP_302_FOUND, "Msg": "something is wrong in uploading logs"}
            return JSONResponse(aws_log)
            # delete log dir if exist
        if os.path.isdir('logs'):
            print("Log File exists")
            shutil.rmtree('logs')
        return JSONResponse(final_res)


We have updated the access creds in code.
we have updated the access creds in aws secrets manager as well.
we have tested that the logs of aws-detection service are getting 200OK but api logs getting this above error.
Questions:

do I need a rekoginition service running on aws for this service to run
do I need any other service to be enabled on aws.
how to get it fixed with this error

